How to "stockpile" drugs which have start and duration
I have a R dataframe which has drug prescriptions for patients as follows:
Patient StartDate    Duration     
 1      01/01/2004      35      
 1      15/01/2004      60     
 1      01/02/2004      15
 1      01/09/2004      30
 2      01/01/2004      30
 2      01/03/2004      30

I want to stack or stockpile these drug prescriptions per patient, if there is an overlap, (assume that the drug is always the same) by changing the start date of each record so that it is after the end date of the previous record. Then the end date of the current record will also change (new_start_date + duration).
So in the above, for patient 1, the end date of the  1st record is 35 days after 01/01/2004, say 05/02/2004, and so the start date of the 2nd record should be changed to 06/02/2004. This also changes the end date of the 2nd record to say, 05/04/2004, and so the start date (and end date) of the 3rd record would have to change accordingly.
This should only happen if the start date of a subsequent record is before the end date of the previous record. So for patient 1's 4th record, and for both records for patient 2, there would be no change because there is no overlap with the previous record.
This can be done by a for loop in R, but I have millions of records so it's very slow. I would like a tidyverse or SQL solution ideally. And yes Chat GPT seems not to provide any valid solutions

Thanks Andre, found it difficult to format the data

I think it would be helpful to extend the example with 1-2 more patients/drugs and, more importantly, a couple non-overlapping dates to check if approaches work as expected in all cases.

Hi Andre, thanks for the suggestion. I've done what you suggested and simplified the data by removing the drug.

See if this works for you.
First spliting to get the groups, then do the iterative re-dating. Finally get the original form back by rbinding the result.
df$StartDate <- as.Date(df$StartDate, "%d/%m/%Y") # setting Date class

data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(split(df, df$Patient), \(x){
    for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
      if(x[i,"StartDate"] <= x[i-1,"StartDate"] + x[i-1,"Duration"]){
        x[i,"StartDate"] <- x[i-1,"StartDate"] + x[i-1,"Duration"] + 1
      }
    }
    x })), row.names=NULL)
  Patient  StartDate Duration
1       1 2004-01-01       35
2       1 2004-02-06       60
3       1 2004-04-07       15
4       1 2004-09-01       30
5       2 2004-01-01       30
6       2 2004-03-01       30

Note that for loops are not per se slow. Just remember to not append objects within the loop and pre-allocate as much as possible.
EDIT: If you have to check if there are Patients with only one row add an if-clause before the for-loop, e.g. if(nrow(x) >= 2). Leave it out if you're sure you never have Patients with just one row. It's a little faster then.
Data
df <- structure(list(Patient = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), StartDate = c("01/01/2004", 
"15/01/2004", "01/02/2004", "01/09/2004", "01/01/2004", "01/03/2004"
), Duration = c(35L, 60L, 15L, 30L, 30L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


This works but is very slow. However converting to a data.table speeds it up so that it works.

You're actually interested in comparing the start date of the current record with the "end date" of the previous record.  So create a new column to contain the information of interest.
Then use a nested ifelse to (1) handle the first record differently and (2) perform the necessary calculation.
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- as_tibble(read.table(
  textConnection(
"Patient    Drug    StartDate    Duration     
1        A        01/01/2004      35      
1        A        15/01/2004      60     
1        A        01/02/2004      15"),
header = TRUE))


df %>% 
  group_by(Patient, Drug) %>% 
  mutate(
    StartDate = dmy(StartDate),
    EndDate = StartDate + days(Duration),
    StartDate = as_date(
      ifelse(
        row_number() == 1,
        StartDate,
        ifelse(
          StartDate < lag(EndDate), 
          lag(EndDate) + days(1), 
          StartDate
        )
      )
    )
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 5
# Groups:   Patient, Drug [1]
  Patient Drug  StartDate  Duration EndDate   
    <int> <chr> <date>        <int> <date>    
1       1 A     2004-01-01       35 2004-02-05
2       1 A     2004-02-06       60 2004-03-15
3       1 A     2004-03-16       15 2004-02-16

Using dplyr::case_when would probaly remove the need for the as_date.  ifelse is annoying when it comes to coercion...
That is indeed the case:
df %>% 
  group_by(Patient, Drug) %>% 
  mutate(
    StartDate = dmy(StartDate),
    EndDate = StartDate + days(Duration),
    StartDate = case_when(
      row_number() == 1 ~ StartDate,
      StartDate < lag(EndDate) ~ lag(EndDate) + days(1), 
      TRUE ~ StartDate
    )
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 5
# Groups:   Patient, Drug [1]
  Patient Drug  StartDate  Duration EndDate   
    <int> <chr> <date>        <int> <date>    
1       1 A     2004-01-01       35 2004-02-05
2       1 A     2004-02-06       60 2004-03-15
3       1 A     2004-03-16       15 2004-02-16

Note the issue this creates in the third record, where the start date is now after the end date.  You haven't defined what you want to do in this case.

Hi Limey, simultaneously with changing the start date for each subsequent record, I must also adjust the end date by adding the (non-zero) duration for that record. If that happens the end date will never be before the start date. Thats what makes this difficult: the end date for each record is dynamically changing as well. Apologies if I didn't make that clear.

Hi Limey, I took out the drug column as it was superfluous to the problem
